# set opacity of all background images to 0 with plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with the logic using this jQuery slideshow plugin.  I don't want to have to set the height of the images because some of them get stretched out too much.  But if the image height isn't set, and the image is short, you can see the other images behind it.  Here's what the code looks like:

html

```
<div id="slideshow1">
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" class="active"/>
    <img src="img/gallery2.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery3.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery4.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery6.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery7.jpg"/>
</div>
```

css

```
#slideshow1{
  position:relative;
  height:450px;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
}
#slideshow1 img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:300px;
  //height:450px;
  z-index:8;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
#slideshow1 img.active{
  z-index:10;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
#slideshow1 img.last-active{
  z-index:9;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
```

js

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ){ 
    $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG:last');
}

var $next;
if ($active.next().length){
    $next = $active.next();
}else{
    $next = $('#slideshow1 IMG:first');
}

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
  setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3000 );
});
```

I tried adding the opacities to last-active in the css but that didn't do the trick.  Is it possible to toggle the background images transparencies without messing up the code too much?

Comment: Have you tried setting the visibility to hidden?

Comment: display:none?  where exactly would I put that?

Comment: No, the visibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility. That won't show an element but the element will still occupy space, whereas changing the display to none will make it act like the element doesn't exist.

Comment: is this you want --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QCe5C/

Comment: YES @TusharGupta that worked perfectly!  Thanks.  Post it as an answer so I can accept it, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QCe5C/)

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG.active');

    if ($active.length == 0) {
        $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG:last');
    }

    var $next;
    if ($active.next().length) {
        $next = $active.next();
    } else {
        $next = $('#slideshow1 IMG:first');
    }

    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $('#slideshow1 img').css('opacity','0.0'); //added this code

    $next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    })
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000, function () {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#slideshow1{
  position:relative;
  height:768px;
  width:1024px;
  float:left;
}
#slideshow1 img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:300px;
  //height:450px;
  z-index:8;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
#slideshow1 img.active{
  z-index:10;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
#slideshow1 img.last-active{
  z-index:9;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function slideSwitch() {

$('img').css('display','none');
var $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ){ 
    $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG:last');
}

var $next;
if ($active.next().length){
    $next = $active.next();
}else{
    $next = $('#slideshow1 IMG:first');
}

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .css('display','block')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
  setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3000 );
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="slideshow1">
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" class="active"/>
    <img src="img/gallery2.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery3.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery4.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/gallery5.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A improvised version this will give you proper transition**

```
function slideSwitch() {

$('img').css('opacity','0');
var $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG.active');
$active.css('opacity','1');

if ( $active.length == 0 ){ 
    $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG:last');
}

var $next;
if ($active.next().length){
    $next = $active.next();
}else{
    $next = $('#slideshow1 IMG:first');
}

$active.addClass('last-active');
$active.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .css('display','block')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });

}

$(function() {
  setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3000 );
});
```